# problems reading output from ffmpeg

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, piping

I am trying to read raw BGR24 image data from ffmpeg into a C++ application. The C++ application will then process the image further using openCV.
jpg -> ffmpeg -> application -> openCV

I started by storing the output from ffmpeg into a file and reading that file from within the application. OpenCV apparently accepts this as it happily displays the image. 
However, it fails when piping the output from ffmpeg directly into stdin of the application.

I changed the program to just save the input to a file and I compared the two files. The first 1856 bytes are the same, but after that the file saved from stdin differs and after that the entire file is just hex D1 (or decimal 209).

[bytes read from stdin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jXdgp.png)

[bytes read from file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uV4ud.png)

I presume that I am making a mistake while reading stdin instead of ffmpeg having a different output. But I find it very strange that the first part is the same.
This is the code I use to read stdin

```
char* img = (char*) malloc(FRM_SIZE_BYTES);
cout << "array address: " << &img;
cout << "array of size: " << FRM_SIZE_BYTES << endl;

int read = int read = read_stdin(img, FRM_SIZE_BYTES);
cout << "read " << read << " bytes" << endl;

int read_stdin(char* buffer, int count) 
{
    int read = 0;
    char in;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        cin >>  in;
        buffer[i] = in;
        read++;
    }
    return read;
}
```

this is how I try to read the file

```
ifstream image;
image.open("img.raw", ios_base::binary | ios_base::in);
std::streampos start, end;  
char* imgFile = (char*)malloc(FRM_SIZE_BYTES);
image.read(imgFile, FRM_SIZE_BYTES);
image.close();
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: try unsigned char instead of a char?

Comment: I tried it but it does not make a difference

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the problem was reading stdin. I am working on a windows machine and did not set the inputstream to binary mode.

Setting the inputstream to binary mode.

```
_setmode(_fileno(stdin), _O_BINARY);
```

and reading the stream like this

```
cin.get(in);
```

fixed the issue.